# Access parent node from virtualDOM before it renders | ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, virtual-dom

I need to set component dimensions depending on parent element. Is it possible to get width and height of parent by ref from virtualDOM before it renders?

Parent

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className={'avocado-container'} ref={(container) => { this.container = container; }}>
          <Resizer parent={this} scrollAxis={'y'}>
          </Resizer>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I need to get the dimensions in constructor of child.

Is is possible with something like `this.refs.container.offsetWidth` ?

Comment: why not to pass them from parent component as props?

Answer (score 0):

**No.** Layout dimensions are calculated by the browser, not the Virtual DOM. Either set the dimensions by hand, or use CSS to make your child component fill width and height. You can also read the width and height from the rendered component in `componentDidMount` and call `setState` in there, which isn't ideal and will cause a second render, but sometimes needs to be done.

Comment: will such component be testable?

Comment: if you need to test the reading of element dimensions flow in didMount, you can use tools like jsdom to supply the neccessary environment. if you don't want to test it, you can do an `if` statement in the didMount to check for the existance of certain objects, like `global.window`

Comment: don't get me wrong, but jsdom hasn't support of getting real width and height of html element, so it will be hard to test without real browser environment asaik